# Drawing dotted line between the cells of UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, core-graphics

I have to achieve something like this(please check attached ScreenShot). The best possible solution which came to my mind is `UICollectionView`. I have created rounded border along the cell and put a button on the cell. Now for the dotted straight line I have used `CAShapeLayer` with `BezierPath` and added the layer to my `collectionview background with background color set to clear color`. Here comes the problem, I am not seeing any dotted line. Here is what I have tried. Now I have couple of questions. While answering please consider me as a beginner.

1) Why my lines are not showing.
2) How to calculate the width between the two cell, right now i am setting a random number.
3) Is there any other approach which can solve this use-case more efficiently.

[image: required]

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
UIBezierPath *borderPath;
CGFloat borderWidth;

KKCollectionCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"testCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
borderPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

[borderPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(cell.frame.origin.x + cell.frame.size.width -1 , cell.frame.origin.y + 2)];
[borderPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(cell.frame.origin.x + cell.frame.size.width + 50,  cell.frame.origin.y +2)];
borderWidth = 1.0;
[self dottedLineWithPath:borderPath withborderWidth:borderWidth];
return cell; 
}

/** creating dotted line **/

- (void)dottedLineWithPath:(UIBezierPath *)path withborderWidth:(CGFloat)lineWidth
{
CAShapeLayer *shapelayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
shapelayer.strokeStart = 0.0;
shapelayer.strokeColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
shapelayer.lineWidth = borderWidth;
shapelayer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinRound;
shapelayer.lineDashPattern = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1],[NSNumber numberWithInt:2 ], nil];
shapelayer.path = path.CGPath;

[self.milestoneCollection.backgroundView.layer addSublayer:shapelayer];
  }
```

**Here is what I have achieved till now**.[image]

Comment: what benefit is the collection view offering you? a grid layout?

Comment: yes, thats why I used it. Cause may be in future the no of circle may be getting increased or decreased. So just to avoid the rework. Whats your suggestion anyway. I am open for any other possibility.

Comment: in order of complexity, but also power: first, use an image for all graphics and overlay the text. then use views laid out on a superview view. then collection view with accessory views.

Comment: Seems little tedious, isn't any simple way of doing it :)

Comment: the image is a simple way - programming isn't easy, if you only ever want a simple solution to problems you're in the wrong business

Comment: I do understand that, but here I have achieved around 80%, the only thing left is the dotted arrow line between the circular view. So, just wondering isn't it possible. Cause there is one more saying "nothing is impossible in programming".

Comment: One more thing to ask, which is the elegant and faster way, using image for small graphics like lines, border(as in the above case) or rendering it through code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hi done this using `UICollectionViewLayout` and draw functions.

[image: screenshot]

Code uploaded in path https://github.com/arunpkumar92/OrderStatusCollectionView

```
- (void)reloadConnections{

    for (CAShapeLayer *shapelayer in self.connectionLines) {
        [shapelayer removeFromSuperlayer];
    }

    self.connectionLines = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (int i = 0; i <= (self.total-2); i++){
        NSArray *paths = [self pathForconnectionLineForIndexPath:i];
        for (UIBezierPath *path in paths) {
            UIColor *color = (self.currentLevel > i) ? [UIColor colorWithRed:0.078 green:0.557 blue:0.067 alpha:1.00] : [UIColor colorWithRed:0.957 green:0.659 blue:0.024 alpha:1.00];
            CAShapeLayer *shapelayer = [self drawdottedLineWithPath:path withborderWidth:1.0f withColor:color];
            [self.collectionView.layer addSublayer:shapelayer];
            [self.connectionLines addObject:shapelayer];
        }
    }

}

- (NSArray *)pathForconnectionLineForIndexPath:(int)index{
    NSMutableArray *paths = [NSMutableArray array];

    int row = index%self.noOfItems;
    int column = index/self.noOfItems;
    CGFloat cellWidth = self.view.frame.size.width/self.noOfItems;
    CGFloat cellHeight = self.view.frame.size.width/self.noOfItems;
    CGFloat connectionLength = cellHeight/2;

    CGFloat leftPadding;
    CGFloat topPadding;

    if (row != (self.noOfItems-1)) {
        leftPadding = cellWidth/4;
        topPadding = cellHeight/2;

        UIBezierPath *borderPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
        CGFloat startX = (3*leftPadding)+(row*cellWidth);
        CGFloat startY = topPadding+(column*cellHeight);
        CGFloat endX = startX + connectionLength;
        CGFloat endY = startY;
        [borderPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(startX , startY)];
        [borderPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(endX,  endY)];
        [self drawDirectionAt:CGPointMake((startX+(connectionLength/2)) , startY) isEnabled:(self.currentLevel > index) isRight:YES];
        [paths addObject:borderPath];

    }

    if ( (row == (self.noOfItems-1)) && (column%2 == 0) ) {
        leftPadding = cellWidth/2;
        topPadding = cellHeight/8;

        UIBezierPath *borderPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
        CGFloat startX = leftPadding+(row*cellWidth);
        CGFloat startY = (7*topPadding)+(column*cellHeight);
        CGFloat endX = startX;
        CGFloat endY = startY + (2*topPadding);
        [borderPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(startX , startY)];
        [borderPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(endX,  endY)];
        [self drawDirectionAt:CGPointMake(startX , (startY+topPadding)) isEnabled:(self.currentLevel > index) isRight:NO];
        [paths addObject:borderPath];

    }

    if ( (row == 0) && (column%2 != 0) ) {
        leftPadding = cellWidth/2;
        topPadding = cellHeight/8;

        UIBezierPath *borderPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
        CGFloat startX = leftPadding+(row*cellWidth);
        CGFloat startY = (7*topPadding)+(column*cellHeight);
        CGFloat endX = startX;
        CGFloat endY = startY + (2*topPadding);
        [borderPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(startX , startY)];
        [borderPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(endX,  endY)];
        [self drawDirectionAt:CGPointMake(startX , (startY+topPadding)) isEnabled:(self.currentLevel > index) isRight:NO];
        [paths addObject:borderPath];

    }

    return paths;
}

- (CAShapeLayer *)drawdottedLineWithPath:(UIBezierPath *)path withborderWidth:(CGFloat)lineWidth withColor: (UIColor *)color
{


    CAShapeLayer *shapelayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    shapelayer.strokeStart = 0.0;
    shapelayer.strokeColor = color.CGColor;
    shapelayer.lineWidth = lineWidth;
    shapelayer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinRound;
    shapelayer.lineDashPattern = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:15],[NSNumber numberWithInt:10 ], nil];
    shapelayer.path = path.CGPath;

    return shapelayer;

}

- (void)drawDirectionAt:(CGPoint)point isEnabled:(BOOL)enabled isRight:(BOOL)isRight{
    NSString *imageName;
    imageName = isRight ? @"right-arrow" : @"down-arrow";
    imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@",imageName,(enabled ? @"enabled" : @"disabled")];

    CAShapeLayer* direction = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    direction.opacity = 1.0;
    direction.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 16, 16);
    direction.position = point;
    [direction setContents:(id)[[UIImage imageNamed: imageName] CGImage]];
    [self.connectionLines addObject:direction];
    [self.collectionView.layer addSublayer: direction];
}
```

Comment: Why down vote ??? what is the reason for down vote. i Can't make full solution of code here. so i a m added external link.

Comment: +1 for your effort, i'll add the bounty after testing both answers. Right now, I am on move so can't test.

Comment: @KunalKumar Why you are not accept the answer, is have any issues? then please add comment

Comment: Not working on iPhone, cells are getting collapsed. Playing with the size of cells and other attributes.

Comment: @KunalKumar : That you should manage. :) I just done a sample iPad app (very Rough) for particular solution. dotted connection and the Flow.

Comment: @Arun: please suggest me how to change the position of vertical arrow. I want the array to be start from upper cell label and end with the down cell label

Answer (score 3):

> Why my lines are not showing.

To get your drawing visible, you have to add your drawing code directly to `UICollectionView` instance and not to it's `backgroundView` property.

```
[self.milestoneCollection.layer addSublayer:shapelayer];
```

This works 100%. Using `backgroundView` may seem like the right thing to do, but they might be using it for completely something else. I doubt `backgroundView` is either not visible at this time (using default configuration) or ignoring our change requests altogether.

[image: Lines_Drawn_Center_To_Center]

> How to calculate the width between the two cell, right now i am setting a random number.

```
-(void)getLineStartPoint:(CGPoint*)startPoint
             andEndPoint:(CGPoint*)endPoint
     fromCellAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)fromIndexPath
       toCellAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)toIndexPath
{
    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes* fromAttributes =
    [self.milestoneCollection layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:fromIndexPath];

    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes* toAttributes =
    [self.milestoneCollection layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:toIndexPath];

    *startPoint = fromAttributes.center;
    *endPoint = toAttributes.center;
}
```

`UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes` is 100% feature rich in geometrical information about `cells, headers, footers, decorationViews` at a particular `indexPath`. For simplicity, I'm now using `center`. I believe you need to use your logic with `frame` property.

> Is there any other approach, which can solve this use-case more efficiently.

YES, there are always two ways.

- Getting it done.
- Getting it done **RIGHT**.

Of course **RIGHT** is different according to the situation and time available.

### KEEP IN MIND

- Be careful with `indexPath` availability or you would very easily crash. Here's a simplest form of guard for this-

  ```
  NSInteger numberOfItems = [self collectionView:collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:indexPath.section];

  if(indexPath.item < numberOfItems-1)
  {
      CGPoint startPoint, endPoint;
      NSIndexPath* toIndexPath =
      [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:indexPath.item+1 inSection:indexPath.section];

      [self getLineStartPoint:&startPoint
                  andEndPoint:&endPoint
          fromCellAtIndexPath:indexPath
            toCellAtIndexPath:toIndexPath];

      [borderPath moveToPoint:startPoint];
      [borderPath addLineToPoint:endPoint];
      borderWidth = 1.0;
      [self dottedLineWithPath:borderPath withborderWidth:borderWidth];
  }
  ```
- Also when you try to scroll it (if needed), layers/paths are added
  every time you create a cell (this results in dark dotted lines due to
  multiple times adding in the layer hierarchy), you need to take care
  of this when reusing cells. Have a look at this :-

[image: Line_Drawn_Multiple_Times.png]

That should answer all of your questions. Best Of Luck!!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll test it and update you.